# How to make filters?

Tags: filters, computer-vision, image-processing, opencv

I am trying to make filters like `sepia filter` in my app like other photo editing applications , till now I don't have any idea about it , Can any one help me out for it about its algorithms and how to do it ? and Can I implement in opencv using native c++ or we have any of its build in functions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at implementations for open source image editing programs (e.g. GIMP). This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163866.aspx) from MSDN Magazine, January 2005 by Stephen Toub, entitled "Sepia Tone, StringLogicalComparer, and More" in the .NET matters section specifies a linear transformation of the color space to get a Sepia effect: "New Red = R*.393 + G*.769 + B*.189 New Green = R*.349 + G*.686 + B*.168 New Blue = R*.272 + G*.534 + B*.131" where each channel is normalized to lie in $[0,1]$.

Its just applying the formula on each pixel, so you don't need any special libraries.

Comment: So do we need to be good at photoshop to get these values or we can just do it by hit and trial method

Comment: Someone played around with the colors to do this (likely, someone who has some intuition for RGB color space). There is also this StackOverflow thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061093/how-is-a-sepia-tone-created

Comment: Can you please tell me about this line " where each channel is normalized to lie in [0,1]" what do you mean by this

Comment: You have your channel values going from 0 - 255. To normalize them , you divide by 255 so they lie between 0 and 1.

Comment: Yeah right , but still we need it if we put conditions like `if ((rgbValues[i + 2]) > 255){
            rgbValues[i + 2] = 255; }` for all colors

Comment: I was just using 0-255 as an example - in most images, this is the constraint (i.e. you have 8 bits per color channel). You just map (linearly, typically) the acceptable values for a parameter to [0,1] to normalize it. Its not a hard idea.